# Firebase push notification postman paramters for schedule fcm

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have to schedule  push  notification,
which parameters i have to pass in postman
Currently i have use these :-

```
{
    "notification" : {
        "title" : "Hey Ankit",
        "body" : "Thanks For visit to my home"
    },
    "to" : ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to schedule the sending of FCM messages through the API. That is currently only possible for messages posted from the Firebase console, or by building your own scheduling mechanism that calls the FCM API at the designated time.

Comment: Any other way to schedule push notification in Angular with firebase